# ROS 2 Bouncy get_parameter

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using ROS 2 Bouncy and I'm trying to get parameters from a yaml file. I checked a few ways to get parameters and I found one that works but takes 3 lines for each parameter :

```
auto ip_port_param = rclcpp::Parameter("ip_port", 10940);
nh_->get_parameter("ip_port", ip_port_param);
ip_port_ = ip_port_param.as_int();
```

Is there a nicer way to get parameters in one line like in ROS 1 ?

```
pnh_.param<int>("ip_port", ip_port_, 10940);
```

I could change `ip_port_` into a `rclcpp::Parameter` instead of an `int` but then I would have to modify the whole code. Would that be the "proper" way to do it ?

I also tried to use `rclcpp::SyncParametersClient` but I can't use it from within a node, I have to be outside of it (ie: in the main) because the class constructor takes a `rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node`. But when I'm in the node if I use `this` I get a `rclcpp::Node*` or if I use `this->shared_from_this()` then it compiles and run but I don't get the parameters, they take the default value.

```
auto parameters_client = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(this->shared_from_this());
ip_port_ = parameters_client->get_parameter("ip_port", 10940);
```

All the examples from the demos pkg that use `rclcpp::SyncParametersClient`, do it from the main and not inside the node.

Whereas for `rclcpp::AsyncParametersClient`, you can use it inside your node with `this` but there is no `T     get_parameter (const std::string &parameter_name, const T &default_value)` function, you have to use a `get_parameters(...)` and then you don't even get the direct values but a vector of `Parameter()`.

Am I missing something or is it just the way we have to get parameters for now ?

Thanks.

Edit :
I can do something like :

```
template <class T>
rclcpp::Parameter get_param (rclcpp::Node* node, std::string param_name, T default_value) {
  auto param = rclcpp::Parameter(param_name, default_value);
  node->get_parameter(param_name, param);
  return param;
}
```

And then :

```
ip_port_ = get_param(this, "ip_port", "").as_int();
```

But I feel like it should be something that's already there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304436/ros-2-bouncy-get_parameter/) by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2018-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's the `get_parameter_or` method:

http://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#ae5d51004e6e4fc32194251587eb8711a

Which would allow you to do something like this:

```
int ip_port_;
node->get_parameter_or("ip_port", ip_port_, 80);
```

And recently the `get_parameter_or_set` which will get it if set, and if not it will set the parameter to the "default" you gave and then return it.

Edit: remove `&` because it's pass by reference not a pointer.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-09-30**:
Both `get_parameter_or` and `get_parameter_or_set` take a `Parameter()` in and not an `int` or `string`, so we can't do this. We would need to do :

```
Parameter ip_port_param;
this->get_parameter_or("ip_port", ip_port_param, Parameter("", 80));
ip_port_ = ip_port_param.as_int();
```

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-05**:
Are you sure? The one I'm looking at takes `ParameterT` which is a template argument.

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-10-07**:
Ok, I had some errors and didn't look much further, my bad, it does work with:

```
int ip_port_;
this->get_parameter_or("ip_port", ip_port_, 80);
```

Need to remove the `&` since we pass by reference, otherwise we get an error.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-08**:
Awesome, glad you got it to work.